# how can I get the window name? [Python]

Tags: python, windows

How can I get the window name?

I want to make a script where I have some keyboard event, and I want it to happens only if the window name has something in the name, like, Firefox.

how can I do it?

the simplest way

Comment: Which window do you mean? The one that currently has focus on the desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "window name" you mean "window *title*", and assuming you have the window's handle in `hwnd`,

```
import win32gui
thetitle = win32gui.GetWindowText( hwnd )
```

You need to download `win32gui` and the other "windows extensions for Python" from [here](http://python.net/crew/skippy/win32/Downloads.html), of course, and install them on your machine.

If you mean something else, please clarify!

Answer (score 2):

## Getting `window.title` using `pyautogui`

There is another method using pyautogui module that can be used to get window titles and it supports usage on Windows

To simply get all of the Window titles and other information on the Windows, you can follow the snippet below.

## Installation

```bash
$ pip install pyautogui
```

### Getting Window Title

```py
import pyautogui
windows = pyautogui.getAllWindows()
for window in windows:
    print(window.title)
```

#### Output:

```bash
Windows Powershell
C:\Users\munee\Desktop\ChessMan\main.py (ChessMan) - Sublime Text (UNREGISTERED)
how can I get the window name? [Python] - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome
untitled • (AdvantedScanPro) - Sublime Text (UNREGISTERED)
Recycle Bin
munee
WhatsApp
Realtek Audio Console
Realtek Audio Console

Calculator
Calculator
Microsoft Text Input Application
```

### Getting Other Window Attributes

In order to get other window attributes you can go ahead and refer the following code snippet and output.

```py
import pyautogui
windows = pyautogui.getAllWindows()
for window in windows:
    print(window)
```

#### Output:

```bash
<Win32Window left="0", top="0", width="1", height="1", title="">
<Win32Window left="0", top="1030", width="1920", height="50", title="">
<Win32Window left="-9", top="-9", width="1938", height="1048", title="Windows Powershell">
<Win32Window left="-9", top="-9", width="1938", height="1048", title="C:\Users\munee\Desktop\ChessMan\main.py (ChessMan) - Sublime Text (UNREGISTERED)">
<Win32Window left="-9", top="-9", width="1938", height="1048", title="how can I get the window name? [Python] - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome">
<Win32Window left="84", top="78", width="995", height="800", title="untitled • (AdvantedScanPro) - Sublime Text (UNREGISTERED)">
<Win32Window left="467", top="0", width="1424", height="750", title="Recycle Bin">
<Win32Window left="435", top="280", width="1424", height="750", title="munee">
<Win32Window left="320", top="108", width="1280", height="813", title="WhatsApp">
<Win32Window left="0", top="1", width="1280", height="1000", title="Realtek Audio Console">
<Win32Window left="100", top="0", width="1298", height="1010", title="Realtek Audio Console">
<Win32Window left="0", top="0", width="1920", height="1030", title="">
<Win32Window left="0", top="1", width="400", height="665", title="Calculator">
<Win32Window left="1310", top="118", width="418", height="675", title="Calculator">
<Win32Window left="0", top="0", width="1920", height="1080", title="Microsoft Text Input Application">
<Win32Window left="0", top="0", width="0", height="0", title="">
<Win32Window left="19", top="0", width="1901", height="4", title="">
<Win32Window left="0", top="0", width="0", height="0", title="">
<Win32Window left="0", top="0", width="0", height="0", title="">
<Win32Window left="-32000", top="-32000", width="199", height="34", title="Select root@DESKTOP-4UA4732: ~/kabaclassifier">
<Win32Window left="-32000", top="-32000", width="199", height="34", title="mo@DESKTOP-4UA4732: ~">
<Win32Window left="0", top="1", width="1280", height="1000", title="Settings">
<Win32Window left="50", top="0", width="1298", height="1010", title="Settings">
<Win32Window left="0", top="0", width="1920", height="1080", title="">
<Win32Window left="0", top="0", width="1920", height="1080", title="">
<Win32Window left="0", top="0", width="1920", height="1080", title="Program Manager">
```

Comment: This solution does not currently work on Linux. 

[on github](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/b4255d0be42c377154c7d92337d7f8515fc63234/pyautogui/__init__.py#L284) it states that this only works for win32.

Comment: @tgb Thank you for your kind comment, I've updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using pyhook, `event.WindowName` in your `OnKeyboardEvent` etc function contains the value xx