# Python get specific window title

Tags: python, win32gui

I want to be able to detect the presence of a specifically named window (in any process) to use as an "if" variable

After some research, I've concluded I must use the `win32gui` library (some posts also suggest `ctypes`), but most of the posts I find are about [making a list of processes](https://sjohannes.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/win32-python-getting-all-window-titles/), and the only one that was related to this topic didn't answer the question properly. Perhaps I am too novice to understand it, but at last, I couldn't get it to work (the question was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706128/how-can-i-get-the-window-name-python))

To exemplify what I want, I'll share a simple `.vbs` code that does that: It searches for a specific name (in our case, steve jobs) and if it finds it anywhere, it triggers (in this example, it closes said process)

```
do
WindowTitle = "steve jobs"
set shell = createObject("wscript.shell") 
success = shell.appactivate(WindowTitle)
if success then shell.sendkeys "%{F4}" 
loop
```

Comment: `win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, None, '<window_title_string>')` is what I use, and check the Trueness of the returned hwnd to determine whether the window was found.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! How do I test for that trueness? I tried using `Test = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, None, 'name')` and then I made a simple `if Test == True:` and it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import win32gui

win2find = input('enter name of window to find')
whnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(None, None, None, win2find)
if not (whnd == 0):
  print('FOUND!')
```

You can search Google for 'FindWindowEx'

to find https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx

for a description of the FindWindowEx function

Comment: I tested it and it worked fine while testing with notepad and such, but for some reason it doesn't work with Google. The original idea I had was to detect google searches, but it doesn't work. I try putting the whole search (for example, if I want to detect "potato" I'll try detecting "potato - Google Search") and it doesn't work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Good point - I took a look at the Task Manager and ... "potato - google-suche - mozilla firefox" works fine in good old germany ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! I just wrote "potato - Google Search - google chrome" and it worked perfectly! I'll instantly check your answer

Comment: I know it has been a long time, but I wanted to ask you, how did you get the window title? As in, I go to Task Manager and I am not shown the window title, just the process ("chrome.exe" appears, and no "potato - Google Search - google chrome")